# SQL: How to count the sum of values without GROUP BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
visitorId    visitNumber   DATE         
1            1             20180101     
1            2             20180101   
1            3             20180105    
2            1             20171230  
2            2             20180106
```

What I would like to return is:

```
visitorId    totalVisits   max_visits_in_1_day  
1            3             2                       
2            2             1
```

I manage to get everything working without `max_visits_in_1_day` using:

```
SELECT visitorId, 
MAX(visitNumber) - MIN(visitNumber) + 1 as totalVisits, 
GROUP BY visitorId
```

What I need to do is improve the code such that `max_visits_in_1_day` gets added. Something like `MAX(COUNT(GROUP BY(DATE)))`

I first tried adding `MAX(COUNT(DATE))`, but this aggregates all dates, and doesn't actually look for maximum unique date. In a sense, I would need to do a GROUP BY on DATE and the sum the counts then.

I tried adding `GROUP BY visitorId, DATE` but this creates extra rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Big Query SQL, I'm not sure what is behind it, it is LEGACY SQL

Comment: I don't understand the dependency between the `DATE` column and the `visitTime` column. How can you have a visit on `2017-12-30` that has a visitTime of `1970-01-01`?

Comment: I just entered arbitrary values (the dependency is incorrect), but the idea of visitTime is just used to calculate time between visits, so it's irrelevant when the count starts, only the time between visits (which is also probably incorrect)

Comment: The question still holds even if we remove that column, it's not actually required, (and time_between_visits)

Comment: You were half way there.  You just needed to separate your steps more firmly.  Aggregate your data down to one row per user per date, allowing you to use `COUNT()` in your aggregation.  Then process those results in another query, aggregating down to one row per user, allowing you to use `SUM()` and `MAX()`.  This is easily done by nesting SQL Queries.  `SELECT a, SUM(y), MAX(y) FROM ( SELECT a, b, COUNT(x) FROM xxx GROUP BY a, b ) AS subquery GROUP BY a`  *(The results of the sub-query are treated as "just any other data-set" such as from a table or view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to take two steps like this:

```
SELECT visitorId, SUM(perDay) AS totalVisits, MAX(perDay) AS max_visits_in_1_day
FROM
(SELECT visitorId, COUNT(visitNumber) AS perDay, DATE
FROM myTable
GROUP BY visitorId, DATE) A
GROUP BY visitorId
```

Comment: The layout hurts my old withered brain cells, but the approach is spot on.  *(Aggregate twice, once to an intermediate level...)*

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query -

```
SELECT visitorId
      ,COUNT(visitNumber) totalVisits
      ,mv1d.count max_visits_in_1_day
FROM YOUR_TABLE YT
INNER JOIN (SELECT visitorId, MAX(COUNT(DATE)) count
            FROM YOUR_TABLE YT1)
ON YT.visitorId = YT1.visitorId
GROUP BY visitorId
```